# DOM Manipulation(Click Event Not Working)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've build an express app and its working perfectly, in the final stage I want to add some alert messages to pop when some button are clicked. But my alerts are poping without even clicking, the moment page containing the button is loaded pop up shows

In my `index.js` file I have a form button for deleting

```
<form
    action="/grades/<%=grade._id%>?_method=DELETE"
    method="POST"
    class="delete-form"
>
    <input
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-danger mt-3"
        value="Delete Class"
        id="delBtn"
    >
</form>
```

I've given ID `delBtn` for the button,
and inside my `main.js` I have

```
var delBtn = document.querySelector('#delBtn');
delBtn.addEventListener('click', alert('Button Clicked'));
```

How can I get this to work properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem. You call `alert` immediatelly.

```
delBtn.addEventListener('click', alert('Button Clicked'));
```

it will behave just like this

```
alert('Button Clicked');
delBtn.addEventListener('click', undefined);
```

The `addEventListener` function expects a string and a function but you are not passing in a function but `undefined` since that is what `alert` function returns.

So all you need is this

```
delBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    alert('Button Clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed callback function in event listener

```
delBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){alert('Button Clicked')});
```